# Why Google Recaptcha returns false after a specific time in java?

Tags: java, recaptcha

I am using Google `reCAPTCHA` in my project. It works fine. But after a specific time, my code is returning the response value is false. It should be true.
**Not always** like this, but after 10 days(for example) returning false.I am not hitting any daily usage limit.

The problem is solving when I restart the server (apache tomcat).
**My code is:**

```
public static boolean verify(String gRecaptchaResponse) throws IOException {
    if (gRecaptchaResponse == null || "".equals(gRecaptchaResponse)) {
        return false;
    } 
    try { 
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // add reuqest header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

    String postParams = "secret=" + secret + "&response="
            + gRecaptchaResponse;

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(postParams);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + postParams);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {

        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    // print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());

    //parse JSON response and return 'success' value
    JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(response.toString()));
    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonReader.readObject();
    jsonReader.close();

    return **jsonObject.getBoolean("success");**
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it return false from the JSON object or from the exception clause?

Comment: I was thinking it would be the problem of the server itself - I have a Tomcat server and it basically "shuts down" every 8 hours, preventing all connections to the server and either returning null or false to every thing that needs a connection... I would recommend running a script of some kind to make a connection to your server every once in a while to prevent it from "shutting down", like my server.

Comment: Hi  Theodoros. It return false from the JSON object. What do you think about this?

Comment: That tells me that it's not a connection timeout or any other similar kind of error in your client. But if the server sent the JSON data with the `false` value, we probably need to examine the server's code. Is that code available to you? And are you allowed to run that code in a debugger?

Comment: The server side code is above. URL = https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify. And when i run that code in a debugger, i take true from the JSON object.